# Checking if the next element is a specific one

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I want to check if the next element after a .sectionheading is a .accordion-group. If not, then I want to remove this .sectionheading. Here is my code, which unfortunately does not work.

```
$('.accordion.accordion-modules .sectionheading').each(function() {
    if ($(this).next() == $('.accordion-group'))
        $(this).remove();
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `hasClass`.

```
if($(this).next().hasClass("accordion-group"));
    // Your other code
```

Comment: It works. I just have added  "!"  to the if query, because I want to check wheter the next element is not an .accordion-group. Many Thanks :)

Comment: I have to wait 30 seconds :D

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to check the element itself as the`$('.accordion-group')` will match new elements.

Perhaps this will work:

```
$('.accordion.accordion-modules .sectionheading').each(function() {
    if ($(this).next().is('.accordion-group'))
        $(this).remove();
});
```